# find out the colour of the title inside a uibutton

Tags: swift, uibutton

You can set the colour of a button by doing `setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)`, which will set the button to white. But what if wanted to check the colour of the title inside the button?

I tried
`let color = titleColor(for: .normal)` and `let color = titleLabel?.textColor` but when I try to set that color elsewhere, nothing happens.

Use:

```
extension UIButton {

func loadingIndicator(show: Bool) {
    let tag = 9876

    var color: UIColor?

    if show {
        color = titleColor(for: .normal)
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        let buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height
        let buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width
        indicator.center = CGPoint(x: buttonWidth/2, y: buttonHeight/2)
        indicator.tag = tag
        indicator.color = UIColor.white
        setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)

        self.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.startAnimating()
    } else {
        if let indicator = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
            indicator.removeFromSuperview()
            setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how are you using the title color elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the color of the title of the `UIButton` with `state` and than you can used it anywhere you want.

```
let color = btn.titleColor(for: .normal);
label.textColor = color
```

As you can see my Button color is correctly used in Label TextColor in this image.
[image]

This is how you will do it in the Extension

```
extension UIButton {

    func loadingIndicator(show: Bool) {
        let tag = 9876

        var color: UIColor?

        if show {
            color = titleColor(for: .normal)
            let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            let buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height
            let buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width
            indicator.center = CGPoint(x: buttonWidth/2, y: buttonHeight/2)
            indicator.tag = tag
            indicator.color = UIColor.white
            setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            self.addSubview(indicator)
            indicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            if let indicator = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
                indicator.stopAnimating()
                indicator.removeFromSuperview()
                setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
//This will set the saved color for `UIButton` title
btn.loadingIndicator(show: false)
```

Comment: hmm. I'm trying to find out the color in a extension. This is so I can save the color, change the color to clear then set it back to the original color. I've added the extension to show what I'm trying to do

Comment: This statement is false if let indicator = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIActivityIndicatorView  when i call loadIndicator with false value. Also you need to take this line setTitleColor(color, for: .normal) outside the if statement, than it will work

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Can you show some code?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work neither. But i figured that I need to save the colour of when the `btn.loadingIndicator(show: true)` is called before I change the color to clear. Then, when I change it back to false I can set the previous color. I've added the code if you're interested looking at it :) That being said thanks for your help

Comment: Actually the code i wrote was specially saving the color and applying, sorry i couldnt understand what you were trying to acheive otherwise i would have fix the issue for you :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, got there in the end :)

Comment: i ll edit my answer in the meanwhile, feel free to upvote it :)